# split a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, threshold

print (df)

```
  A  B  
  0  10  
  1  30  
  2  50  
  3  20  
  4  10  
  5  30


  A  B  
  0  10  
  1  30 

  A  B
  2  50

  A  B
  3  20  
  4  10  
  5  30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using `numba` to speed up our `for loop`:

We check when our limit is reached and we reset the `total` count and we assign a new `group`:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumsum_reset(array, limit):
    total = 0
    counter = 0 
    groups = np.empty(array.shape[0])
    for idx, i in enumerate(array):
        total += i
        if total >= limit or array[idx-1] == limit:
            counter += 1
            groups[idx] = counter
            total = 0
        else:
            groups[idx] = counter
    
    return groups

grps = cumsum_reset(df['B'].to_numpy(), 50)

for _, grp in df.groupby(grps):
    print(grp, '\n')
```

**Output**

```
   A   B
0  0  10
1  1  30 

   A   B
2  2  50 

   A   B
3  3  20
4  4  10
5  5  30
```

---

**Timings**:

```
# create dataframe of 600k rows
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*100000, ignore_index=True)
dfbig.shape

(600000, 2)

# Erfan
%%timeit
cumsum_reset(dfbig['B'].to_numpy(), 50)

4.25 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Daniel Mesejo
def daniel_mesejo(th, column):
    cumsum = column.cumsum()
    bins = list(range(0, cumsum.max() + 1, th))
    groups = pd.cut(cumsum, bins)
    
    return groups

%%timeit
daniel_mesejo(50, dfbig['B'])

10.3 s ± 2.17 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Conclusion**, the `numba` for loop is 24~ x faster.

Comment: You can get a large speedup in your Numba function  if you use a numpy array for `groups` instead of a list.

Comment: I tried that, but got an error that `type of variable cannot be determined`. @max9111

Comment: It should be possible with allocating a array with `groups = np.empty(array.shape[0],dtype=np.uint64)` instead of `groups = []` and writing the result to the array using `groups[idx]=counter` instead of `groups.append(counter)`.

Comment: I see, that worked indeed, will edit answer. I tried with `groups=np.array([])` and then `groups = np.append(groups, counter)`. That gave me an error. @max9111

Comment: Hi @Erfan I thanks for the answer but I will need to split the data always in 6 bin based on the threshold is that possible I tried to edit yout code but it does not work: if total >= 50 or array[idx-1] == 50 and goups==3:

Answer (score 4):

You could do use [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) on the cumulative sum of the B column:

```
th = 50

# find the cumulative sum of B 
cumsum = df.B.cumsum()

# create the bins with spacing of th (threshold)
bins = list(range(0, cumsum.max() + 1, th))

# group by (split by) the bins
groups = pd.cut(cumsum, bins)

for key, group in df.groupby(groups):
    print(group)
    print()
```

**Output**

```
   A   B
0  0  10
1  1  30

   A   B
2  2  50

   A   B
3  3  20
4  4  10
5  5  30
```

Comment: Hi Daniel do u know how can i give the groups different names to call them later

Comment: You can put them in a dictionary

Comment: @DanielMesejo you might be interested in the timings in my answer. Didn;t expect a `for loop` with `numba` to be that much faster.

Comment: @Erfan Indeed is a lot faster, I guess numba is a really great tool